# Rally: Create an app where the user stories are listed against the Test Cases which they are linked to

Tags: javascript, rally, user-stories, defects

Rally: Create an app where the user stories are listed against the Test Cases which they are linked to.

I am using the rally.sdk to get the same.

```
var queryConfig = { 
    type: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
    key : 'stories',
    fetch: 'Name,TestCaseStatus,TestCases'
};

var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__', 
    '__PROJECT_OID__',
    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', 
    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__'); 
rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, displayStory);
```

When i display the TestCases field it gives me 
`[object Object]`

How do I get to access the TestCaseID. 
I also tried to use a few variables which are part of the HierarchicalRequirement: 
c_TestCasesCreated.  This doesnt work and renders nothing.

I am not sure how I can get the solution to the same.

Please help

Thanks,

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

The TestCases field on User Story object is a collection of Test Cases, and you need to iterate over the collection to get to the FormattedIDs and other fields of individual elements of the collection. Here is the code:

```
 var rallyDataSource = null;
 var iterDropdown = null;
 var table = null;

 function showUserStoriesTable(results) {

  for (var i=0; i < results.stories.length; i++) {
        var t = " ";
    if (results.stories[i].TestCases){
            console.log(results.stories[i].TestCases.length);
            for(var j = 0; j < results.stories[i].TestCases.length; j++){

                t += "  ";
                t += results.stories[i].TestCases[j].FormattedID;
            }
            results.stories[i].TestCases=t;
    }

   }

   var tableConfig = {
     columnKeys : ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'TestCases' ],
     columnWidths : ['80px', '360px', '400px']
   };
   table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(tableConfig);
   table.addRows(results.stories);
   table.display(document.getElementById('stories'));
 }

function onIterationSelected() {
   if(table) {
    table.destroy();
   }
   var queryConfig = {
     type : 'hierarchicalrequirement',
     key : 'stories',
    fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,TestCases',
     query: '(Iteration.Name = "' + iterDropdown.getSelectedName() + '")',
     order: 'Rank'
  };
   rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, showUserStoriesTable);
 }

 function onLoad() {
   // rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__','__PROJECT_OID__','__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__','__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('111111','222222','false','false');  //IF RUNNING OUSIDE OF RALLY USE OIDs
  var iterConfig = {};
   iterDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.IterationDropdown(iterConfig, rallyDataSource);
   iterDropdown.display(document.getElementById("iterationDiv"), onIterationSelected);
 }

 rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
```